# Two conditional based replace function over same list in prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I need to replace elements in a list based on its value, for certain type of value I need to execute one kind of replacement and for the second one I have an auxiliar function that returns the element that I want to use as replacement, so:

```
%receives a character (a 'code') and returns a list with other characters (the 'value' of that code)
auxiliarFunction(Char, Response)
```

An exampleof what I need to do:

I neeed a function receiving a list of numbers and letters. If the letter 'a' appears, I want to replace it with the character `*` and concat it to the `Res` variable, but if it is not 'a' I need to call `auxiliarFunction` and concat `Response` to `Res` (let's assume that it's going to be the name the number as a `list` of letters, this is just an example because the real auxiliar function is complex, but the output it is simple).

Pseudo code:

```
replaceChars([], [])
replaceChars([X|Xs], Res)
% if x == a then Res will have [*] (concat '*' to Res)
% else auxiliarFunction(X, Response) and concat Response to Res (Response will be a list)
% replaceChars(Xs, Res) make recursion call
```

For example, a valid input could be `[2,a,2,a]` and the output (Res) it should be `[t,w,o,*,t,w,o,*]`.

How can I make these two conditional replacement-functions over the same list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if A then B else C` is written in prolog as `A -> B ; C`

```
replaceChars([], []).
replaceChars([X|Xs], Res) :-
    replaceChars(Xs, Res1),
    (  X = a
    -> Res = [* | Res1]
    ;  auxillaryFunction(X, Response),
       append(Response, Res1, Res)
    ).
```

I think the validity of input should be checked seperately, `isValid(Xs), replaceChars(Xs, Ys).`

```
isValid([_]).
isValid([a, X | Xs]) :- dif(a, X), isValid([X|Xs]).
isValid([X, a | Xs]) :- dif(a, X), isValid([a|Xs]).
```

Comment: I edited the question, validation not needed, but your solution works perfectly